# Can't update or remove ruby-net-telnet

Tags: package-management, updates, dpkg, ruby

Running Ubuntu 16.04. All other packages update fine but attempting to update or remove ruby-net-telnet returns errors

```
Preparing to unpack .../ruby-net-telnet_0.1.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ruby-net-telnet (0.1.1-2) over (0.1.1-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-net-telnet_0.1.1-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory
Selecting previously unselected package libruby2.5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libruby2.5_2.5.1-1bbox1~xenial4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libruby2.5:amd64 (2.5.1-1bbox1~xenial4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby2.5.
Preparing to unpack .../ruby2.5_2.5.1-1bbox1~xenial4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ruby2.5 (2.5.1-1bbox1~xenial4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-net-telnet_0.1.1-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried numerous solutions from different forums including:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

From [this post](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-package-operation-failed-error-in-ubuntu/) which fits my problem exactly

I've tried creating the `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/` directory and an empty md5sums file, but that did not work.

The project page for ruby-net-telnet shows the last update as:

2016-03-01 - Christian Hofstaedtler 
ruby-net-telnet (0.1.1-2) unstable; urgency=medium

- Team upload.
- Set Multi-Arch: foreign to allow crossinstall of ruby itself
- Update Standards-Version to 3.9.7 (no addtl. changes)

Any ideas appreciated.